# Authentication Error in Hermes JMS while Connecting to Tibco EMS 8.2

Tags: jms, soapui, tibco, tibco-ems, hermes-jms

I am using Hermes v1.4 SOAP UI to connect with Tibco EMS 8.2. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.rubix.nl/blogs/using-soapui-and-hermesjms-tibco-ems).

**Problem:**

After doing all the settings , when I tried to connect with EMS server which is running on local machine. It is giving me authentication error.

[image]

I provided the default username and password that is "admin" and "admin". 
I can see the following error in my EMS console.

[image]

Why my EMS server is not authorizing the Hermes JMS to connect? Do I also need to do anything on EMS Side as well. Please guide.

Comment: Check where you exactly set the credentials, it needs to be set on queue level and factory level (2 times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default there is no password for TIBCO EMS. You can try with username `admin` and password `''`(empty). Hopefully, it will solve you your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:
1. Right-click on free space in plugin section and press “Add property”. 
2. You have to enter all three properties: username, password and serverURL 
3. Do the same for Connection Factory 
4. Give the username as "admin"

Please refer attached screenshot for more details[image]